# Función filtrar en el prototipo de Arrays

Tags: javascript, array, callback

Hola soy nueva en el mundo js y estoy teniendo varios problemas al momento de realizar este ejercicio. Intente recorrerlo con un foreach y darle validaciones adentro. Pero me dio error, después use map para el nuevo array pero no me salió.
Quería saber si me podrían ayudar dandome una mano o guía porque estoy trabada. Muchas gracias!

```
function filtrar(funcion) {
  // Escribi una función filtrar en el prototipo de Arrays,
  // que recibe una funcion (callback) que devuelve true o false.
  // filtrar los elementos de ese arreglo en base al resultado de esa funcion
  // comparadora, devolver un nuevo arreglo con los elementos filtrados.
  // NO USAR LA FUNCION FILTER DE LOS ARREGLOS.
  // ej:
  // var productos = [{
  //   price: 100,
  //   name: 'tv'
  // }, {
  //   price: 50,
  //   name: 'phone'
  // }, {
  //   price: 30,
  //   name: 'lamp'
  // }]
  // productos.filtrar(function(p) {
  //   return p.price >= 50;
  // }) => [{price: 100, name:'tv'}]

  //Esto es lo que intente pero nada :(
  // Array.prototype.filtrar = function(cb) {
  //   let newArray = [];
  //   for(let i=0; i<this.length; i++) {
  //       const x = cb(this[i]);
  //       newArray.push(x);
  //   }
  //   return newArray;
  // };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu solución iba bien encaminada, pero hay cosas por corregir:

Debes definir el método *filtrar* antes de ejecutarlo, tú lo tienes después y estás agregando todos los elementos en lugar de analizar el resultado de la función de retorno (callback) para saber si debe agregarse o no.

Al ejecutar el método, tienes bien definida la función de retorno, pero sobra la parte final  `=> [{price: 100, name:'tv'}]`, no entiendo lo que querías lograr con eso, pero genera un error de sintaxis.

Finalmente, hay que obtener el valor devuelto en una variable o mostrarlo directamente en la consola.

```js
var productos = [{
  price: 100,
  name: 'tv'
}, {
  price: 50,
  name: 'phone'
}, {
  price: 30,
  name: 'lamp'
}];

// Definir el método antes de ejecutar
Array.prototype.filtrar = function(cb) {
  // Crear el arreglo que se va a devolver
  let newArray = [];
  // Recorrer elementos actuales
  this.forEach(item => {
      // Analizar el resultado de la función de retorno o "callback"
      if(cb(item)) {
          // Si devuelve verdadero, agregar elemento
          newArray.push(item);
      }
  });
  // Devolver arreglo filtrado
  return newArray;
};

// Ejecutar método de filtro proporcionando función de retorno o "callback"
let filtrado = productos.filtrar(function(p) {
  // Incluir solo productos que cumplen esta condición
  return p.price >= 50;
});

// Mostrar resultado
console.log(filtrado);
```

Comment: Gracias! me quedo clarisimo, al ser nueva en esto me cuesta pero bueno se avanza de a poco, gracias nuevamente por contribuir

Answer (score 0):

Hay un pequeño error en tu función:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    const x = cb(this[i]);
    newArray.push(x); <---------- En esta parte estas agregando la respuesta de la funcion.
    //Que suele ser true o false al array de respuesta. Tienes que devolver this[i] que es el 
    //valor de esa iterancion dentro del array
    //Tambien te falta el if para saber si cumple o no la condición 
  }
```

Tu codigo deberia quedar algo asi:

```
Array.prototype.filtrar = function (cb) {
  let newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    const x = cb(this[i]);
    if(x)newArray.push(this[i]);
  }
  return newArray;
};
```

Y este es un código propio donde separe un poco mas los valores en variables por si te sirve de referencia

```
Array.prototype.myFilter = function (callback) {
  const array = this;
  const response = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
    const element = array[i];
    const filter = callback(element, i);
    if (filter) {
      response.push(element);
    }
  }
  return response;
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

```js
 var productos = [{ price: 100,name: 'tv'}, { price: 50, name: 'phone' }, { price: 30,name: 'lamp'}];
   
Array.prototype.filtrar = function(funcion){
  let array = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
     if(funcion(this[i])){// que recibe una funcion (callback) que devuelve true o false.
        array.push(this[i]);// if true o false: filtrar los elementos de ese arreglo en base al resultado de esa funcion comparadora
     }
  }
  return array;
}
    
let res = productos.filtrar(function(p) {
  return p.price >= 50;
});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const products = [
    { price: 100, name: "tv" },
    { price: 50, name: "phone" },
    { price: 30, name: "lamp" }
];

const priceCriteria = (price) => price > 80;

function filtrar(funcion) {
    let newArray = [];
    products.forEach(product => {
        if (funcion(product.price)) {
            newArray.push(product);
        }
    })
    return newArray;
}


console.log(filtrar(priceCriteria));
```